# Bootstrap 3 and Yootheme Widgetkit Conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement BS 3 on Joomla 3.1.5. I had the site working until I installed widgetkit now the site is broken. (http://mountainairmechanical.com/new/) I did a fresh install of Joomla (http://mountainairmechanical.com/j3/) with some factory content. On the original site the Widgetkit install has broken it completely. I have tried reinstalling Widgetkit and then re-uninstalling with no luck. Uninstalling on the other site returns the functionality. The only plugins installed are JCE and only on the original site, the second site has no additional plugins installed.

Is it possible to get Widgetkit to work with Jquery 1.10.2 which is the most current version and the version that BS3 supports?

Update:

If widgetkit is uninstalled everything works correctly.

Yes everything worked prior to Widgetkit install. If I uninstall it on the second site listed it works fine.

Comment: It appears that the links to the bootstrap files are broken. Check your console.

Comment: Whwne you uploaded the Bootstrap 3 css and js files before installing the Widgetkit, did it work? The Widgetkit would not interfere with any custom template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to get this working through much trial and error. Had a couple of things going on. But mainly what I can determine is Widgetkit 2.5 doesn't like jQuery 1.10. I had to do a noConflict and load both jQuery 1.8.3 and 1.10. Also had to experiment alot with the order of the javascripts. Placing them all at the bottom (as you should) caused strange bugs to creep up. Thanks to **MasterAM** for letting me know that the BS files were broken.